# Fragments with Listview activity appends

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have implemented a view as splitview with fragments, when click on any listview item, the other part of splitview should show a specific view, kindly check my code for creating view and suggest me what am i doing wrong as when i click on list view items multiple time, the webview appends horizontally

```
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) {
    int n;
    Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(c);


    LayoutInflater inflater1= (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
    View view=inflater1.inflate(R.layout.webview,container,false);  
    l.addView(view);

    return l;
}
```

Comment: We need the code with the FragmentTransaction that adds the Fragment.

Comment: Fragment f = new TestFragment(nAndroids);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.the_frag, f);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

Comment: Sure, all code is shown? For example: What about the unused "int n" doing? And why use the LinearLayout. It is completely unnecessary - and potentially harmful, because the LayoutInflater depends on the correct container. But you add your inflated child to something different (the LinearLayout). That's not good!

Comment: so how can i add my webview programatically

Comment: Just let go of LinearLayout and return `view` instead of `l`.

Comment: yup i did that even, the whole view appends using that technique @WolframRittmeyer

Comment: So why not show all of it. The Activity and the Fragment. Complete and unabridged.