# Popoverview android button OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have implemented popoverview to show three buttons in it, the popoverview is shown from some base activity, now i want to implement the functionality of popoverview button to do some change in the activity on which it is shown, i've implemented showing popoverview using the following link

```
                 https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView
```

Kindly suggest me how can implement onclicklistener for popoverview, the implementation has methods like:

```
            popoverViewWillShow
            popoverViewDidShow
```

Comment: I can't figure out the exact question.

Comment: there are buttons on popoverview and i want to implement onclicklistener for them,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a a simple custom view. After you call `showPopoverFromRectInViewGroup` simply use `findViewById` on the `Popover` instance to find your `Buttons`.

Comment: kindly look at the following stack question as well and suggest any solution if you have any clue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417576/fragments-with-listview-activity-appends